# SWT Popup Menu width

Tags: java, swt

I have a tree with various items in it. When I right-click in the tree a menu pops up. The heading in the menu can vary in width depending on the position in the tree (item under the mouse)

```
  ivPopMenuTree.setText( targetPath );
```

If the `targetPath` has 10 characters, that is the width of the menu. When `targetPath` has 30 characters, the menu width expands to show the entire path. However the next time the menu pops up, and `targetPath` is 10 characters, the menu width does not shrink and instead shows the 10 characters with 20 spaces following.

Is there a way to have the menu width only show the width of the current text? Something like `.requestLayout();`?

Comment: `Menu` and `MenuItem` sizes are determined by the native controls SWT calls. SWT doesn't decide on the sizes. It might help if you show us a [mre] so we can check the code.

Comment: @greg-449 Well the ```ivPopMenuTree.setText( targetPath );``` is actually the minimal code :-)  I would have to show the shell, the tree, the code creating the tree items, then the listener class which pops up the menu. The target path is derived from the tree item, walking the tree down to its root. So the deeper the tree, the longer the path. The MenuItem seems to remember its last width, and will not adjust to shorter text even though it adjusts to longer text. I was hoping there was a method which would force the TreeItem to re-adjust its width dependent on the **current** text value.

Comment: You could try rebuilding the menu from scratch each time you need to show it, which is common practice.

Comment: @greg-449 Yes, that had crossed my mind. It's only six items so would not take very long. I was just hoping for a more elegant solution... Thanks

Comment: Rebuilding the menu everytime is so common that the JFace `MenuManager` has options and listeners specifically for this.